# Order of form_load method execution

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating a winforms application which uses Gmaps.net. I am unable to alter the order in which on Load methods are being called. For some reason the map_load is being called before the man_Load. Is there any way to change the order of this ?

If I can provide any more information to help just ask.
Thanks!
Dan.

```
public partial class main : Form
{
    public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("main_load");
    }

    private void map_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("map_load");
    }
}
```

Comment: The the `map` control initialized in the `main` form's constructor (`InitializeComponent()`)? I.e. is it something made at design time? If it is you can create the control entirely at runtime inside your form's load event...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you used the WinForms designer to create the map. The code behind is in the `InitializeComponent()` method and seems that the map is being loaded before the `MainForm` is loaded.

My recommendation is to create the map, once the MainForm has been loaded:

```
public partial class main : Form
{
    public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control map = CreateMap();
        map.Docking = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(map);
    }

    private Control CreateMap()
    {
       // Create a new GMaps.NET object, intialize it and return
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.